# Net Framework 4.5 causes a program to crash

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, .net-framework, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Sony Vegas is crashing the moment I press render regardless the format chosen on a freshly installed Windows 8.1.

Error:

[image]

```
    Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: vegas130.exe
  Application Version:  13.0.0.428
  Application Timestamp:    5463a76e
  Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.5.27.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   545ca861
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000006c854
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1cf0
  Additional Information 2: 1cf0e7963731731fc6a78a515dc4d96a
  Additional Information 3: ea9d
  Additional Information 4: ea9de657ddafbdc1a4be657754c9b9f2
```

I ran sfc /scannow and Windows Updates but no errors were found.

Luckyly I found a solution in this thread ([Vegas closes upon any attempt to render](https://forums.creativecow.net/readpost/24/985362)): Clr.dll in Net Framework 4.5 causes Vegas to crash, this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103) claims to fix it. However this hotfix is only applicable to Net Framework 4.0, and Windows 8.1 comes bundled with 4.5.

Net Framework repair tool won't provide a repair option:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And attempting to repair Net Framework using this command fails to work:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

[image]

What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: The hotfix you linked to is for `.NET Framework 4.0` applications.  `Windows 8.1` has `.NET Framework 4.5.x` by default which is an in-place replacement for `.NET Framework 4.0.x`, in otherwise the hotfix does not apply to your operating system.  Due to the age of the hotfix I would be shocked if it had not already been rolled into a later version of `.NET Framework 4.0` anyways

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I will deviate the question from the hotfix.

Comment: Even if you were running `Windows 7` with `.NET Framework 4.0.x` installed based on the problem signature and the signature described in the support article, they are not even close, the exception offset isn't even the same.  I assume you have install all available updates?

Comment: You will need to use the DISM tool against a `Windows 8.1` installation since your `WinSxS` directory appears to be empty.  Your `WinSxS` source directory not existing is a separate problem you should solve.

Comment: WinSxS has many folders and is 6.63 GBs large. Do you suggest to replace this folder with a WinSxS copy from another Windows 8.1 installation?

Comment: No;  You instead need to use an installation disk as the source, so your own component store can be fixed, then use SFC to repair the damage if it exists.

Comment: That means running the installation disk with recovery mode and entering the DISM command?

Comment: I dont think your .NET installation has any issues. Its with Sony Vegas. Just that it crashes in clr.dll

Comment: Hi Ganesh, yes, so far Sony Vegas is the only program having this issue, I tested different Vegas versions and the result is the same. My old computer works perfectly with Vegas and Windows 8.1.

Comment: You don't need to boot into WinRE in order to run DISM against local Source.  The entire idea is to repair the online source ( i.e. your installation ).

Comment: Ramhound can you provide a documentation link? I'm completely new to this DISM workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 RC ([DP46-KB3006563-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45497)) and the error is gone!